# How to remove modal having unwanted background in twitter bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]This is the code of the modal where I am using bootstrap3.

Also using the patch file specified here : http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/

Added image that I am getting as an output.

What is the exact problem causing here ? can someone please help on this.

---

```
<div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-focus-on="input:first"     style="width: 700px;">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
       <h1 class="text-center">Login</h1>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
     <form class="form col-md-12 center-block">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Sign In</button>
          <span class="pull-right"><a data-toggle="modal"  href="#registerModal">Register</a></span><span><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></span>
        </div>
      </form>
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span> | Login via Facebook</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><span class="fa fa-google-plus"></span> | Login via google</button>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="col-md-12">
       <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
   </div> 
   </div>
  </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: There look like there may be a couple of errors there. Is <div class=" col-md-5 co![.......][2] l-md-offset-1"> correct? Also col-md-1accordion2?

Comment: @bigfish66 : Thanks for pointing out. those err came while pasting here. edited question. Same problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem but it happens just in small screens like tablets and smartphones.

I'm using a Joomla template and in a CSS file, I found some code as below:

```
@media only screen
```

So I believe that if you use code inspect (chrome/Firefox/opera), maybe you will find a way to fix this.